# How to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing in webforms single-file page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to execute an **aspx webforms single-page** on a server. I need to use the **DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing** in the page.

How should I add reference or import the namespace of the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing in the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Assembly Name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml,version=2.0.5022.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging" %>
```